# Maximise sumproduct of column values Python

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am looking to maximise the sumproduct of two columns in a dataframe. For example if I can buy something and then sell it later (i.e. I can store it) how would I write some Python code to work this out for me?

This is a very simple example. If you plot the prices you will see they are low in the summer, then high in the winter. If there are no contraints and I want to buy 100 lots I would buy all 100 at 9 in July, costing me 900 (as it is the cheapest month). Then I would store it until February (as it is the most expensive month) and sell it for 13.5, getting me 1350 i.e. a 450 profit.

If for some reason the maximum I can buy and sell in a month is 30 lots, then I would buy 30 in June, July and August, then 10 in September. I'd sell 10 in December, then 30 in January, February and March. I'd do all this in order to maximise the total money I can make [i.e. total of all price * sold minus the total of price * (bought)].

The total row shows me I'd make 450 or 362.5 in these situations. I have just done this by simply looking it at as it is very obvious. But how can I get Python to do this for me? I looked at the SciPy optimise page, but didn't get too far.

Essentially I want to maximise the total row by allocating a certain amount of buying and selling in each month - targeting the max I can buy in the cheapest months with a spill over into the next cheapest months etc, then selling at the max prices, spilling over into the next most expensive months etc.

So if I have 100 lots to buy and the prices change tomorrow, then how does my strategy change. E.g. if June went to 8 then I should shift my max buying to June.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


start_date = dt.datetime(2019, 4, 1)
end_date = dt.datetime(2020, 3, 1)
dates = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='MS')

df = pd.DataFrame([10.5, 10, 9.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 12.75],
                      columns=['Price'],
                      index=dates)

df['No Constraints'] = [0, 0, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0]
df['Money In (Out) No Constraints'] = df['Price'] * df['No Constraints']

df['Max 30'] = [0, 0, -30, -30, -30, -10, 0, 0, 10, 30, 30, 30]
df['Money In (Out) Max 30']= df['Price'] * df['Max 30']

df.loc['Total'] = df.sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first situation, the strategy is pretty simple:
Whenever the price rises you buy as much as possible, whenever the price fall you sell all, and at the end of the year, you sell all of them. I don't quite understand your words, you have 100 dollars and the price is 9, how do you buy 100?
My code like this:

```
prices = [10.5, 10, 9.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 12.75]

my_money = [100]*(len(prices)+1)
my_stock = [0]*(len(prices)+1)
for i in range(len(prices)):
    if i != len(prices) - 1 and prices[i + 1] > prices[i]:
        buy = my_money[i]//prices[i]
        my_money[i+1] =my_money[i]%prices[i]
        my_stock[i+1] = my_stock[i] + buy
    else:
        my_money[i+1] =my_money[i] + prices[i] * my_stock[i]
        my_stock[i+1] = 0

print(my_money)
print(my_stock)
```

For the second case, unless again I misunderstood your description, your strategy is obviously far from ideal. For one thing, the price is lower consistently for the first few months so you can keep buying 30 for the first months, and keep selling them for the last few months. 
Realizing this algorithm may be a little complicated to understand. I like to think in terms of day and stocks so it will be like this from now on. Basically you have a 2D array my_money[day][num_of_stock], this counts the maximum of money you can have if you are holding `num_of_stock` amount of stock on the `day` number of day. `my_money[day+1][j]` is the maximum of (my_money[day][i] + prices[day] * (i - j)), where i is all the possible number of stocks you hold the previous day and j is the number of stock you may hold today, considering your constraints. And in the end, your maximum reward is the my_money[-1][0], which is the most money you can have with no stock in your hand the last day.
It's a little complicated, but I think the code better explains this.
see the code:

```
prices = [10.5, 10, 9.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 12.75]
MAXSELL = 30

my_money = [[] for _ in range(len(prices)+1)]
my_money[0].append(0)

for day in range(len(prices)):
    j = 0
    while(j < len(my_money[day]) + MAXSELL):
        max_stock = min(len(my_money[day]),j + MAXSELL + 1)
        min_stock = max(0 , j - MAXSELL)
        moneyj = max([(my_money[day][i] + prices[day] * (i - j)) 
                      for i in range(min_stock, max_stock)])
        my_money[day + 1].append(moneyj)
        j += 1
print(my_money[-1][0])
```

The output is 472.5, which is larger than your result.

Alternatively, if you still have the money cap (100), and can't spend to negative, this slightly modified code does that:

```
my_money = [[] for _ in range(len(prices)+1)]
my_money[0].append(100)

for day in range(len(prices)):
    j = 0
    while(True):
        max_stock = min(len(my_money[day]),j + MAXSELL + 1)
        min_stock = max(0 , j - MAXSELL)
        moneyj = max([(my_money[day][i] + prices[day] * (i - j)) 
                      for i in range(min_stock, max_stock)])
        if moneyj > 0: 
            my_money[day + 1].append(moneyj)
            j += 1
        else:
            break
print(my_money[-1][0])
```

Which expectedly gives the same result as case 1 since maximum of 30 buy/sells are impossible to happen when you only have $100